# Eval in Common Lisp

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, eval, common-lisp

I am new to lisp, and here is my question:

I have a list that is something like

```
((a ((length 3) (size 5))) (b ((length 5) (size 7))))...
```

The above list is just a sample. 

What I am trying to have is a function `find` that can work like a database query, for example

```
(find (and (gt length 4) (lt size 8)))
```

I this case, the above function should find `b` for me. Note that the conditional argument of this function can be expand with `and` or `or` ...

I did some research and know `eval` can somehow help me with this, but I am not sure how it works exactly.
Can someone please show me an example or give me some hint on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog post looks related to your problem: http://xach.livejournal.com/131456.html

(you have to expand it with a small mapping between `length` and `size` and actual values for each of your records, so the closure chain can be called on each of your records)

Answer (score 5):

I would not use eval for this. But it would be relatively easy to do so.

You have a sequence of items:

```
((a ((length 3) (size 5)))
 (b ((length 5) (size 7))))
```

You have a test description, like this:

```
(and (> length 4) (< size 8))
```

Now you want to see if

```
(my-equal '(and (> length 4) (< size 8)) '((length 5) (size 7))
```

is true.

So the task would be to write `MY-EQUAL`. Typically I would write it as a recursive function.

But if you want to do it with `EVAL`, it gets relatively easy:

You want to eval this form:

```
(let ((length 5) (size 7))
  (and (> length 4) (< size 8)))
```

Now it should be easy to write MY-EQUAL.

You can use it then as

```
(find term sequence :test #'my-equal :key #'second)
```

Note, that evaluation of arbitrary code read from a stream is a security risk.

**Bonus**

We can use `COMPILE` instead of EVAL:

```
(defun lookup (v bindings)
  (let ((result (assoc v bindings)))
    (if result
        (second result)
      (error "variable ~a not known" v))))

(defparameter *query-operators* '(and or > < =))

(defun generate-query-code (q bindings)
  (cond ((numberp q) q)
        ((symbolp q) `(lookup ',q ,bindings))
        ((consp q)
         (destructuring-bind (op . args)
             q
           (if (member op *query-operators*)
               `(,op ,@(mapcar (lambda (arg)
                                 (generate-query-code arg bindings))
                               args))
             (error "Unknown op ~a" op))))))

(defun compile-query (q)
  (compile nil
           (let* ((bindings (gensym "bindings"))
                  (code (generate-query-code q bindings)))
             `(lambda (,bindings)
                ,code))))

(defun find-query (query descriptions)
  (find-if (compile-query query)
           descriptions
           :key #'second))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 39 > (find-query '(and (> length 4) (< size 8))
                         '((a ((length 3) (size 5)))
                           (b ((length 5) (size 7)))))
(B ((LENGTH 5) (SIZE 7)))
```